# How to resolve 'Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.' in my code

Tags: java, exception

```
String replaceSubString(String orignal, int startIndex, int endIndex, String replaceWith){

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(orignal);

    if ((action.getEndindex() - action.getStartindex()) < 0) {
        if (replaceWith.length() > (startIndex - endIndex)) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Replace string lenght not same as difference of start & end index.");

        }
        buffer = buffer.replace(endIndex, startIndex, replaceWith);
    } else {
        if (replaceWith.length() > (endIndex - startIndex)) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Replace string lenght not same as difference of start & end index.");

        }
        buffer = buffer.replace(startIndex, endIndex, replaceWith);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Hi , This is my code while i check it for code quality it is showing  'Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one" what should i do to resolve this problem? can anyone help me with that.

Comment: Fix the spelling of lenght. That will improve my mood and I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing a `RuntimeException` which is pretty much as generic as you can get. It's telling you to use something that more accurately tells what went wrong, defining your own `StringLengthException` (or whatever you want to name it) and throwing that instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur immediate reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing `RuntimeException`, which is quite generic, you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (since you throw your exception when your method receives illegal arguments) or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (since  you throw your exception when your method receives indices which are out of the valid bounds).

Comment: Thank you so much for ur immediate reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code quality is asking you to define your own exception instead of using a pre-defined java exception class.

So you should declare a new class (like `ReplaceStringLengthException`) inherited from `RuntimeException`, or you can throw any exception derived from RuntimeException.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur immediate reply :-)